# Count rows in loop for Sum of Column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to search Excel for a change in text in Col G and then sum the values in the 3 Col before. So far this works except the sum is static to x rows. I need it to be dynamic on the "RowCount" any help would be great. I am a couple days into it.

```
Dim iRow As Integer, Tags As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer


Set oRng = Range("G2")

iRow = oRng.Row
Tags = oRng.Column

Do
' 
If Cells(iRow + 1, Tags) <> Cells(iRow, Tags) Then
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 1).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 2).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 3).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 4).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 5).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 6).Interior.Color = 65535
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags).Value = Trim(Cells(iRow, Tags - 6) & " " & (Cells(iRow,     Tags)) & " Totals")
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 6).Value = Array("Totals")
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-40]C:R[-1]C)"  <<<<<<<<< the -40 I want to  be the Integer of “RowCount”
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-40]C:R[-1]C)"  <<<<<<<<< the -40 I want to be the Integer of “RowCount”
Cells(iRow + 1, Tags - 3).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-40]C:R[-1]C)"  <<<<<<<<< the -40 I want to be the Integer of “RowCount”
iRow = iRow + 2
RowCount = 0
Else
iRow = iRow + 1
RowCount = RowCount + 1
End If
```

Comment: `"=SUM(R[" & RowCount & "]C:R[-1]C)"`

Answer (score 0):

First compute the RowCount. Maybe this is what you want:

```
RowCount = iRow - 1
```

Which means you want to sum starting from the second row. You may need to tweak it.

Then

```
"=SUM(R[-" & RowCount & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, need quotes and & around RowCount

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & RowCount & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```